# How and how to replace the GO batch separator?

Tags: c#, sql, sybase

I wrote a program that sends sql queries to the Ase Sybase server.
This miracle works with the help of Ado Net Core.AseClient and in general successfully copes with this.

The key feature is sending a request to several selected servers at once. This is convenient, but when it comes to long procedures with GO separators, here it successfully reports:

Incorrect syntax near 'go'

I know why this happens, since Transact-SQL does not support this separator. Of course, the GO operator is recognized by SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS), sqlcmd and osql, but I am interested in a crutch that will work on AseClient.

Comment: You will need to split your full command text on that GO separator, and send as separate requests

Comment: `go` is not part of the T-SQL language understaood by `ASE`; `go` is a client-side command; this tells the client (eg, `isql`) when to submit a batch/request/operation to the dataserver; as Hans has mentioned, you need to replace the `go` clauses with whatever your app uses to submit a new batch/request/operation to the dataserver

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

because as you mentioned `go` command is not a transactional command and its not recognized by SQL Server.
only sql server clients like sqlcmd and SSMS can benefit that to send separate batches of transcations to sql server.

so your sql client (AseClient) doesn't have this feature.

read more about go command [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/sql-server-utilities-statements-go?view=sql-server-ver15)